# OSGI - CDI / is it usable right now ? [Oct 2012]

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, cdi

I'm quite new to Java EE 6 and OSGI concept, and i'm quite excited about it...

The most exciting feature is the dynamic dependancy injection at execution time.

I've seen some really great presentation where the application is ajaxly updated when a bundle is activated or unactivated, i like that way of decoupling the application in modules and updated it at run time ...

Second though, i'm quite boring about XML configuration files, i think Java EE 6 with `javax.inject` and others annotations is a really good thing...

So, I'm quite ready to start using OSGI for my webapp but first i need some information..

I can't find a clear Status for the progress of the OSGI - CDI Integration in a Java EE Containter.

(gf-cdi-osgi-integration / osgi-cdi / osgi-cdi-api)

I think the question invoke weld-osgi too.

1. Does the latest glassfish 3.1.2.2 support CDI annotation for OSGI like
   @OsgiService and @Publish ? 
   or will it be release in a future release ?

(I've seen samples using @OsgiService and maven depenmdancy that seem to enable this annotation but nothing about @Publish for now...)

1bis - Does Jboss AS support that feature ? Which of theses Java EE container has the best integration with OSGI ?

1. What is fighterfish (Oracle) and is it related to glassfish osgi ?
2. So basically if i want to developp war with cdi and osgi now which env do i need

   (Server - Version - Plugins )
3. Moreover which maven dependancy are required to be able to use @publish and @osgiservice
4. And just to clarify something, can i use hibernate with OSGI in my project if i accept that hibernate lib are packed in my war / wab and will not be provided as bundle

   Same question for any others lib ...

Thanks for your time and explanation, btw i've already read lots of forum and blog https://github.com/tangyong/gf-cdi-osgi-integration 
for example , i just need a clear answer to my question :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFgXPs251po

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A future version of JBoss AS7 (unfortunately I don't have a date) will include the new weld osgi (http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/NotOneTwoWeldReleases1110FinalAnd120Beta1) which will probably do what you want. As for GlassFish, I wouldn't expect to see a weld 1.2.x version in there anytime soon :(

Comment: Thanks.. im rdy to go to jboss for that ..  but afaik glassfish has a better osgi implementation by providing all jee module as bundle so i m gonna check jboss progress

Comment: btw can i replace jboss weld by the provided weld-1.2.0-beta1 ? or its not compatible ? if it is should i just replace weld-core / api / spi modules or others ? which version of jboss can do that (i currently have 7.1.3 (CI version)

Comment: The integration SPI has changes so you won't be able to simply swap out the jar, sorry.

Comment: So what's the way to make it work ? i mean, i think that the weld-1.2.0 release can be tested to check for bug and test the new functionality ? is there any jboss branche that work with it?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is. You'd have to ask the weld-dev list or the JBoss dev list.

Comment: Well in fact Weld 1.2 work on Pure OSGi container ... like Felix ... its can't be integrated to hyberid container cause of the dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Glassfish already supports using Java EE annotations in OSGi bundles. The Document below shows what can already be done which I think is quite impressive. Among others @OsgiService is supported.

http://glassfish.java.net/public/GF-OSGi-Features.pdf

Comment: According that glassfish provide all Entreprises bundles and some Annotations in the Final version , yes its impressive ... but i can't wait to use big new features like OSGI Event and @publish provided by WELD 1.2 !

Comment: I will also watch weld closely as I mostly use Apache Karaf. Do you know if weld works with Karaf?

Comment: AFAIK the weld-1.2.0-Beta1 provided 4 examples based on Equinox, Felix and 2 others ..

Answer (score 2):

Apache Karaf now also supports CDI by using the [pax-cdi](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI) project.

[In a mailing list thread on ops4j](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ops4j/KpOA11LgYSI) Harald Wellman describes how to use pax cdi on karaf.
This worked fine for me. The upcoming karaf 3.0.0 will have pax cdi included in the enterprise feature so installation will then just be "feature:install cdi".

Start Apache Karaf 3.0.0.RC1

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/0.4.0/xml/features
install mvn:org.apache.xbean/xbean-bundleutils/3.12
feature:install pax-cdi-openwebbeans
install mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi.samples/pax-cdi-sample1/0.4.0
start org.ops4j.pax.cdi.sample1
```

So we can check if the example works:

```
services org.ops4j.pax.cdi.sample1

OPS4J Pax CDI Sample1 (153) provides:
------------------------------------
[org.ops4j.pax.cdi.sample1.impl.VanillaService,
org.ops4j.pax.cdi.sample1.IceCreamService]
[org.ops4j.pax.cdi.sample1.IceCreamService]
[org.ops4j.pax.cdi.spi.CdiContainer]
```