# PAX-CDI: inter bundle producer methods

Tags: java, osgi, cdi

With PAX-CDI: How can I define a producer method in one bundle and consume it in another bundle?

I guess since in PAX-CDI inter bundle bean injections has to use the OSGi service registry, the @OsgiServiceProvider annotation is also used for producer methods.

And since I want a different instance for each injection point, I guess I need the prototype scope.

So I tried (among other things):

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...

@Produces
@OsgiServiceProvider
@PrototypeScoped
public Logger getLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
}
```

And on the consumer side I tried:

```
@Inject
@OsgiService
private Logger logger;
```

But it's not working.

I'm getting different exceptions depending on the execution environment.

Eg. with Pax Exam:

```
testParameterizedTypeSupported(org.ops4j.pax.cdi.test.InterBundleProducesTest)  Time elapsed: 10.043 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookupException: gave up waiting for service org.slf4j.Logger
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookup.getService(ServiceLookup.java:199)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookup.getService(ServiceLookup.java:136)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.inject.internal.ServiceInjector.injectField(ServiceInjector.java:89)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.inject.internal.ServiceInjector.injectDeclaredFields(ServiceInjector.java:69)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.inject.internal.ServiceInjector.injectFields(ServiceInjector.java:61)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.createTest(ContainerTestRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:68)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.invokeViaJUnit(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:124)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:97)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:73)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.call(NativeTestContainer.java:109)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.invoke(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:109)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner$2.evaluate(ProbeRunner.java:267)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner.run(ProbeRunner.java:98)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

And in my project environment I'm getting even if I don't have a consumer:

```
ERROR: org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender (41): [CdiExtender(33)] The activate method has thrown an exception
org.ops4j.lang.Ops4jException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001406: Cannot inject [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @OsgiServiceProvider @PrototypeScoped public somepackage.SomeClass.getLogger(InjectionPoint) in a non @Dependent scoped bean
    at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.weld.impl.WeldCdiContainer.doStart(WeldCdiContainer.java:99)
    at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.spi.AbstractCdiContainer.start(AbstractCdiContainer.java:89)
    at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender.impl.CdiExtender.createContainer(CdiExtender.java:132)
    at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender.impl.CdiExtender.addingBundle(CdiExtender.java:86)
    at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender.impl.CdiExtender.addingBundle(CdiExtender.java:44)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:415)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)
    at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender.impl.CdiExtender.activate(CdiExtender.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:231)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:624)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:508)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:149)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:871)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:838)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:850)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:931)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:895)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1480)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1401)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1210)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:1148)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1432)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:987)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:838)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:545)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4547)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3521)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:350)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:1003)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:992)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:1044)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:841)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:419)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:376)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:172)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.<init>(BundleComponentActivator.java:120)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:258)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$000(Activator.java:45)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:185)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:479)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:414)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:443)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:913)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4531)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2169)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001406: Cannot inject [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @OsgiServiceProvider @PrototypeScoped public somepackage.SomeClass.getLogger(InjectionPoint) in a non @Dependent scoped bean
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateMetadataInjectionPoint(Validator.java:327)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:279)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
ERROR: org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender (41): [CdiExtender(33)] Failed creating the component instance; see log for reason
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it is not possible to use @Produces over bundle boundaries. 
You can offer and inject an OSGi service of course but it will not work for your case. You want the Logger to be created for each bean and have a different logger name that depends on the bean class. This is not possible with OSGi services. You create a service once and inject it.

For logging the whole effort you do is not really necessary. Just use the slf4j factory as outside OSGi. It should work fine.

Comment: AFAIK, this should be possible with OSGi v6 using the PrototypeServiceFactory (https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/PrototypeServiceFactory.html). PAX-CDI supports PrototypeServiceFactory with the @PrototypeScoped annotation.

Comment: I'm not introducing CDI just for logging in my framework but as a new major, integrated feature.
Injecting a Logger has the benefit of reducing copy & paste errors.

Comment: Currently I assume that it should be technically possible using the PrototypeServiceFactory, but I think it's not implemented yet. I filed an issue here: https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXCDI-197

Comment: Since you provided the only answer I will award you the bounty anyway. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Does this mean PAX CDI should not be used for inter-bundle service injection?

Trying to follow the samples from [pax-cdi-samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.cdi/tree/master/pax-cdi-samples), I'm able to get the IceCreamService playing, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888325/osgi-cdi-is-it-usable-right-now-oct-2012/19903151#19903151).

I'm now struggling to apply this for my problem where I want a singleton service to be provided by one bundle and to be injected into another bundle.

Any word of advice?

Comment: You use CDI for injection inside the bundles and services to connect bundles. So you can use CDI to export a service in bundle A and import the service in bundle B. What you can not do is pure CDI injects that span bundles.